# Akka Actors and message Throttling

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am trying to write some code against a very old database which crashes if its hit very hard.

I am looking for ways in which my actor does not process more than X messages per second.

Right now, I guess the default implementation of the actor is that it processes the messages in its messagebox as fast as possible.

But I wonder if there is a way I can configure my actor so that there is a limit of "X" number of messages per second from the actor message queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [`TimerBasedThrottler`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/contrib/throttle.html):

```
val printer = system.actorOf(Props[PrintActor])

// The throttler for this example, setting the rate
val throttler = system.actorOf(Props(
  classOf[TimerBasedThrottler],
  3 msgsPer 1.second))
throttler ! SetTarget(Some(printer))
```

And then send messages via the throttler `ActorRef`.